# navigation bar disappearing

Tags: iphone

I have a right bar button on the navigation bar of root view controller. Here is the code

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{

    [self.navigationItem setTitle:@"Contacts"];

UIBarButtonItem *addbtn = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"Add Contact"      style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(btnClick:)];
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = addbtn;

    [tblview reloadData];
}
```

When i click on that button i do get successfully navigated to the next view but when i return back to the root view controller the navigation bar gets disappeared. Please h elp me out as i am new in iphone app development.

Comment: by using this much of code we can't do anything some where also you went wrong?

Comment: Yes, I agree with @Sunny check your code. Only this code is not help

Comment: I don't know what else could be the problem. debugged the whole code. Couldn't find anything.. :( Anyways thanks.. :)

Comment: may be some wher else you are hiding the navigation controller.

Comment: Can you post the method btnClick? Also follow sunny's suggestion that you might be hiding the navigation bar.

Comment: Pess **command+f** then enter `self.navigationItem` or `self.navigationbar` or `self.navigationController` and try to find where else you're using it .... may be you're hiding this somewhere.

Comment: Yes. i have been hiding the navigation bar in next view.. Thanks a lot.. Problem solved now.. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be you are hiding your navigation bar in nextView

so just remove this line in nextView

```
[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES];
```

Comment: Yes. i have been hiding the navigation bar in next view.. Thanks a lot.. Problem solved now.. :)